# Determine value of the integration

Tags: integration

Determine value of the integration $$I=\iint_{D} \sqrt{\left|y-x^2\right|} \, dx \, dy$$ with $$D=[-1,\: 1]\times [0,\: 2]$$

My tried:

$$I=2 \int_0^1 \left(\int_{x}^{2}\sqrt{y-x^2} \, dy\right) \, dx+I_1$$

Find $I_1$.

Answer (score 1):

An idea: the wanted integral seems to be

$$2\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_\sqrt x^1\sqrt{x^2-y}\,dydx+2\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^\sqrt x\sqrt{y-x^2}\,dydx+2\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_1^2\sqrt{y-x^2}\,dxdy$$

Comment: I think $$I=2\int_1^2\int_\sqrt{x}^2\sqrt{y-x^2}dydx+2\int_0^1\int_0^\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x^2-y}dydx$$